# My unique children

Tags: riddle

I am new here. I really like puzzles, riddles and logic thinking. So, as an introduction, I created a very easy riddle. Hope it is good enough for everyone. :D

> Can someone help me what should I do with my children?  They are really a unique bunch but no one likes to be with them.
>
> My oldest child is very temperamental. He is always red with anger and likes to yell at other people.
>   My second child is quite the opposite of my eldest. She is not as loud and angry as my oldest, but she definitely likes to ignore everyone.
>   My third child likes to dance. I've gotta say he is one hell of a shaker.
>   My fourth child.. Hmm, what can I say? She just follows my third child all around.
>   My fifth child keeps on following her older sister (refering to the fourth child). Those three rarely split up.
>   My sixth child is really hot, I mean, literally hot. I guess his condition also affects his appetite as he doesn't like to eat.
>   And lastly, my seventh child, still a baby. Oh, how I wish he would stop crying. He has been crying ever since he was born.
>
> It is saddening. It seems like everyone hates them. This is quite depressing for a parent.
>
> **Can you tell me who my children are?**

I am not sure if this concept/theme already exists, so I apologize if there is already one like this. :)

**Hint 1**

> What the parent says about them as a whole is relevant: "Everyone really *hates* them." Though the parent might be wrong on *hate*, maybe everyone is avoiding them for some other reason besides *hate*?

**Hint 2**

> The only important order is 3rd-4th-5th child. Note that the parent only mentioned that these three rarely split up.

**Hint 3**

> The theme doesn't require someone to be really scientific. It is a common theme, maybe check out the news? You might get some *inspiration*.

Comment: it seems like a valid riddle. Thanks for creating.

Comment: Thank you! I'm quite nervous though, I hope the answer is satisfactory. :) Thanks again!

Comment: @user14303 If you only accept the binary definition of `unique` then it loses all meaning because everything in the universe is unique. Two hydrogen items are unique because, even though they are identical in every measurable way, they are still two separate atoms: this one and that one. I think OP should return the "very" modifier if they feel it is appropriate. I found an [article](http://www.mysteriousexhortations.com/?p=871) that summarizes my opinion pretty well.

Comment: For the second child, "...she definitely likes to ignore everyone" makes me think of Helium, since it's element #2 and is inert.

Comment: Are the genders of the seven children relevant?

Comment: @tfitzger Nope, the genders are not relevant.

Comment: Not dwarfs, sins, roman numerals, wonders of the world, colors of the rainbow, days of the week, continents or planets - as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Raystafarian I am thinking it is days of the Week.

Comment: @Raystafarian The theme isn't any of those you mentioned.

Comment: When you talk about "children" are you referring to people?

Comment: @Raystafarian what about the nature 7 wonders of the world?

Comment: I don't know why, I immediately though of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbapapa

Comment: I'm on to natural disasters or meteorological disasters. 3-4-5 can be tied with 3 being earthquake. And 6 is "hot and fast" wildfire or heat wave. I can't make it all work though.

Comment: are there specifically only 7, or could there be more that are excluded?

Comment: @managedresource There can be more than 7.

Comment: @TʀᴇᴠɪAᴡᴀᴛᴇʀ That's part of the riddle. ;)

Comment: This thing has been plaguing me since I first saw it - great riddle!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thought I'd post my comment as an answer given that Takeshi has confirmed some of it - though I'm still a little uncertain on a few.

*My oldest child is very temperamental. He is always red with anger and likes to yell at other people.*

1. > Volcanic Eruption (loud, spews red lava)

*My second child is quite the opposite of my eldest. She is not as loud and angry as my oldest, but she definitely likes to ignore everyone.*

2. > Blizzard (quiet and not many people are out in it; opposite of hot is cold)

*My third child likes to dance. I've gotta say he is one hell of a shaker.*

3. > Earthquake (shake shake shake)

*My fourth child.. Hmm, what can I say? She just follows my third child all around.*

4. > Tsunami (follows earthquakes all around, even in rings)

*My fifth child keeps on following her older sister (referring to the fourth child). Those three rarely split up.*

5. > Flood (usually a result of a tsunami that hits land)

*My sixth child is really hot, I mean, literally hot. I guess his condition also affects his appetite as he doesn't like to eat.*

6. > Wildfire (hot and moves *fast* (to abstain from eating))

*And lastly, my seventh child, still a baby. Oh, how I wish he would stop crying. He has been crying ever since he was born.*

7. > Thunderstorms (usually raining, though sometimes in FL we go with just lightning and thunder)

And I would say the narrator is *Mother Earth*.

Comment: Great job @Raystafarian! Though, a quick edit on 1 would be Volcanic Eruptions. My initial for 6 is drought (hot, dry and shortage of food) but wildfires can also work!

Answer (score 3):

Let me take the plunge, following @Raystafarian's idea

My oldest child is very temperamental. He is always red with anger and likes to yell at other people.

> Sand storm. Yelling refers to the loud winds

My second child is quite the opposite of my eldest. She is not as loud and angry as my oldest, but she definitely likes to ignore everyone.

> Blizzards. Quieter, but forcing people to stay at home

My third child likes to dance. I've gotta say he is one hell of a shaker.

> Earth quake

My fourth child.. Hmm, what can I say? She just follows my third child all around.

> Tsunami follows earthquake

My fifth child keeps on following her older sister (refering to the fourth child). Those three rarely split up.

> Landslides also follow earthquakes

My sixth child is really hot, I mean, literally hot. I guess his condition also affects his appetite as he doesn't like to eat.

> Heat waves, dries things out without consuming them

And lastly, my seventh child, still a baby. Oh, how I wish he would stop crying. He has been crying ever since he was born.

> Flooding, from rainstorms.

For an over all theme of

> Natural disasters.

I suspect that this is not right, but hopefully it will earn us a hint!

Comment: That's exactly the theme! Though, for the eldest child, take note that he is always 'red' with anger. For the fifth child, notice that he/she follows the 4th child and not the 3rd child. The 6th child, I have a different answer, but yours makes sense and it still works. For the last child, the correct answer is (Rain/Thunder)storms.